# Переопределение методов экземпляра класса в c++

Tags: c++

В java можно сделать так:

```
public interface SomeClass{
    void doSomething();
}

public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(){
            @Override
            void doSomething(){
                System.out.println("Any text");
            }
        }
        someClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

и это бы работало, вывело бы "Any text".
Можно ли подобное реализовать в c++ (Пользуюсь visual studio)?

Comment: Добавьте поле `std::function<void (void)>`, инициализируйте его в конструкторе и вызывайте из  `doSomething`.

Comment: @VTT вместо `std::function` можно использовать простой указатель на функцию.

Comment: В С++ нельзя переопределить метод у конкретного класса. Но можно создать экземпляр класса либо в конструкторе либо в метод `doSomething` передать указатель на функцию либо лямбду. Возможно это вам подойдет

Comment: @Anton спасибо, а можно ли создавать новый класс-наследник прямо в операции приравнивания, вроде - 'SomeClass* class = new class : public SomeClass{ void doSomething override(){ cout << "new text"; } }'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
// Абстрактный базовый класс
class SomeClass
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

// Класс наследник (public - все, что было публичным, то публичным и останется)
class SomeClass2 : public SomeClass
{
public:
    // определяем реализацию метода
    // если версия с++ ниже 11, то без слова override
    virtual void doSomething() override
    {
        std::cout << "Any text" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Два варианта использования:

```
// Через указатель
int main()
{
    SomeClass * a = new SomeClass2();
    a->doSomething();
    delete a;
}

// Через ссылку
int main()
{
    SomeClass2 b;
    SomeClass & a = b;
    a.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Этот код не переопределяет методов в конкретных экземплярах класса. Все экземпляры `SomeClass2` вызовут один и тот же метод.

Comment: Поскольку метод `doSomething` определен только в `SomeClass2`, то да. Если создать еще один класс, который будет наследоваться от `SomeClass`, то в нем можно задать другое поведение для `doSomething`. Ну и сейчас заменю в ответе слово переопределяем на определяем, потому что так будет точнее, раз в базовом классе метод чисто виртуальный

Comment: Да, но есть ли способ для переопределения метода у конкретного экземпляра класса?

Comment: Например имеется list с объектами класса и нужно добавить ряд объектов того класса, но с переопределённым методом. А потом поочерёдно проходить по элементам list и вызывать этот метод. Создавать в таком случае множество классов-наследников будет неудобно.

Comment: Только через наследование. В джаве это тоже делается через наследование (точнее в данном случае через реализацию интерфейса). В плюсах, в отличии от джавы, нет возможности задать реализацию в момент использования - нужно это делать явно и заранее